# Are all quantum algorithms hidden subgroup algorithms?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, research, hidden-subgroup-problem

I am reading the paper "Quantum Hidden Subgroup Algorithms: An Algorithmic Toolkit" by Samuel Lomonaco and Louis Kauffman from the book, "Mathematics of Quantum Computation and Quantum Technology."  See also, this [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0607046) link.

The authors suggest that all quantum algorithms may be hidden subgroup algorithms in the sense that they all find hidden symmetries, i.e., hidden subgroups. Indeed, quantum hidden subgroup (QHS) algorithms encompass Deutsch-Jozsa, Simon's, Shor's factoring algorithm, and more.

The authors suggest of the following meta-procedure for quantum algorithm development:

1. Meta-Step 1: Explicitly state the problem to be solved.
2. Meta-Step 2: Rephrase the problem as a hidden symmetry.
3. Meta-Step 3: Create a quantum algorithm to find the hidden symmetry.

The authors leaves the reader with the questions: "Can this meta-procedure be made more explicit?"

This is article is from 2008. Have their been any developments in the past 15 years building on this idea, or proving that all quantum algorithms are indeed hidden subgroup algorithms?

Comment: Perhaps if you can find a BQP-complete problem, it might be so… Can HHL be rephrased as a hidden subgroup problem? HHL is from 2010, and is BQP-complete, unlike the others you mention.

Comment: HHL: given $A$ and $b$, find $x$ such that $Ax=b$. As a hidden subgroup: find the kernel (a subgroup of vectors) of the matrix $[A | -b]$.

Comment: @SamJaques very interesting - can you expand on that? What does the notation $[A\vert -b]$ mean? Is that a group itself? And under what operation- matrix multiplication? What is hidden? I have some ideas about your statement, but not positive. The kernel maps to $\mathbb 1$? Most quantum algorithms return an NP certificate - as generators of the hidden subgroup. But HHL doesn’t have a certificate that’s classically verifiable. If HHL could be reframed as a BQP-complete HSP, would that answer in the affirmative Lomomaco and Kauffman?

Comment: I mean concatenation of matrices (not sure if there is a standard notation for that, sorry), so if $A$ is $n\times n$ then $[A|-b]$ is an $n\times(n+1)$ matrix where $-b$ is the last column. The group would be $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ under addition, where the kernel is the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $(x, 1)$. 

I guess HHL doesn't *really* solve this hidden subgroup problem, since it gives you $\vert x\rangle$, not $x$ itself.

Comment: @SamJaques that might still be on the right path, though…

Comment: [Did We Overgeneralize to the Hidden Subgroup Problem?](https://dabacon.org/pontiff/2005/05/04/did-we-overgeneralize-the-hidden-subgroup-problem/) a blog post by [@‪Dave Bacon](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/189/dabacon)

Comment: Actually... I'm skeptical that what I said was interesting. Take any NP problem, and let $U$ encode a circuit that decides, given $| x\rangle |w\rangle$, whether $w$ is a witness for $x$. Then the span of $|x\rangle|w\rangle$ for all $x$ in the language and all valid witnesses $w$, is a subgroup in the same way, and applying $U$ (possibly by adjoining a single column to it) is the function that hides this subgroup.

Comment: Even more generally: take any language $L \in \{0,1\}^*$ and define a free vector space over $\{0,1\}^n$ for some $n$ (e.g., formal linear combinations of $n$-bit strings), and let $f$ be any function (whether or not it's even computable!) such that $f(x)=0$ for $x\in L$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\notin L$. Extend $f$ linearly (letting its image be a formal vector space over $\{0,1\}$) and then the preimage of $0$ is a (coset) of the span of $L$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, I am reviewing some literature on this topic. This is **still an open problem** if we talk about **general** Hidden subgroup problem (say, g-HSP), including both abelian and non-abelian cases.

An alternative reformulation of the problem makes it more approachable (and sound). This goes as follows:

*If a classical computer ($P$ or $BPP$) has access to a g-HSP solver (as an oracle), can it solve all the problems in $BQP$?*

Or, does $BQP\subseteq BPP^{(g-HSP)}$ hold true?

This is considered too broad/complex to attack due to the diverse nature of g-HSP problems.
For example, some g-HSP problems are in BQP (i.e., finite abelian HSP). But some are conjectured to be outside BQP, such as (a version of) shortest vector problem; it is NP-hard [[Ajtai, 1998]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/276698.276705).

As pointed out by @Mark Spinelli, we need to know whether we have a BQP-complete in g-HSP. One of the crucial results in this line of reasoning is due to Scott Aaronson (2006) [[see cstheory.se post]](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1298/68722). This is restricted to the abelian HSP (say, a-HSP) case. It says any **a-HSP** solver is (most likely) **not powerful enough** to solve a BQP-complete problem. Or, $BQP \not\subset BPP^{(a-HSP)}$ is probably true.